# Peut-on utiliser « innovant » en tant qu'adjectif ?

Tags: usage, adjectifs, néologismes, participe-présent

Il semblerait que non. Je viens de découvrir que le terme *innovant* est le participe présent du verbe *innover*, mais l'adjectif n'existe pas.

Or, depuis [une vingtaine d'années](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=innovante&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=), on trouve un peu partout les termes « solution innovante » ou « entreprise innovante ». Est-ce un abus de langage ? Une erreur grossière ? Un néologisme qui entre dans les usages ?

Comment: Je plaide pour *un néologisme qui entre dans les usages*.

Comment: si novateur existe dans le dictionnaire, pourquoi utiliser innovant qui n'y est pas?

Comment: Oui, en effet. Et pourtant (je sais que ce n'est pas un critère, mais c'est révélateur), une recherche de "novatrice" donne 1,7 millions de résultats sur Google alors que "innovante" donne plus de 5 millions de résultats !

Comment: http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/innovant

Comment: oO... Ha ben mince, j'aurai du chercher un peu plus loin (et vérifier mes sources). Me voila bien ennuyé maintenant... :/ Je pense que je peux supprimer cette question sotte dans ce cas.

Comment: L'emploi de *innovant(e)* en tant qu'adjectif est très récent, et je pense que la question est tout à fait pertinente.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec Stéphane. Le titre a peut-être besoin d'une reformulation puisque la question porte principalement sur *innovant*, mais je ne crois pas qu'elle soit *too localized*.

Comment: Mais tous les verbes peuvent passer comme adjectif, non ?... Un ruisseau chantant, une vallée riante, une voiture pétaradante, un homme charmant. J'imagine qu'il y a une racine issue du latin ou assimilé, que l'on néologise en verbe, nom, adjectif, etc ? C'est un procédé néologisant, voire même une néologisation dans la néomodernité.

Comment: Innovateur se trouve dans le dictionnaire, avec la même signification, mais bien moins utilisé. Par contre voir la réponde de Un francophone qui explique pourquoi les adjectifs verbaux identiques (en graphie et en sens) aux participes présents n'ont pas besoin d'être dans le dictionnaire.

Answer (score 12):

Pour moi les adjectifs verbaux sont une forme normale des verbes qui ne méritent une entrée dans le dictionnaire que quand ils ont acquis une signification propre ou quand ils présentent une variation orthographique par rapport au participe présent (ceux qui sont en *ent* plutôt qu'en *ant* principalement).

Il ne me semble pas être dans un de ces cas et donc l'absence d'*innovant* des dictionnaires n'est pas pour moi *surprenante* (terme qui mérite une entrée ne serait-ce qu'à cause du tour *surprenant de*).